# How to get all survey answer by current user with REST Api Sharepoint?

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint

In sharepoint survey API:

Get all question: https://site/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Survey')/fields?$filter=(CanBeDeleted eq true)

Get all answer: https://site/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Recognition%20Awards%202019')/items

Get all answer by current user login: ???

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use **_spPageContextInfo.userId** to get the current login user Id, then using **$filter=AuthorId eq UserId** to get all the answer by current user login.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getItems() {
    var listTitle="Recognition Awards 2019";
    var currentUserId=_spPageContextInfo.userId;

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listTitle+"')/items?$filter=AuthorId eq "+currentUserId,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
             //
        },
        error: function (err) {
            //alert(err);
        }
    });
}
</script>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Get Items" onclick="getItems()" />
```